# Why does Neovim behave differently from Geany when launched with nohup and &?

Tags: nohup, nvim, geany

When I open [Geany](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geany) I need to launch it with [nohup](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nohup), e.g. `nohup geany test.txt &` so that when I close my shell,
from which I launched it Geany does not get closed. I noticed that this is not the case
with [Neovim](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nvim), simply `xdg-open test.txt` is enough (provided that I had run `xdg-mime default nvim.desktop text` beforehand). Executing `nvim test.txt &` or `nohup nvim test.txt &` results in the process being launched but without the editors window even being visible.

**1.** In the situation described above, why go **Geany** and **Neovim**  behave differently?

**2.** In the environment where I have access to `nvim` binary but have not done yet (or cannot run) something like `xdg-mime default nvim.desktop text` or `mimeopen -d .txt`, how might I launch `nvim` in a new window so that it does not get closed when I close the shell from which I launched it?

P.S. I use Bash.

Comment: Have you tried this iwth nvim-qt instead? or gvim?

Comment: @user10489 No, I have not. Compiling it from their repo does not produce `nvim-qt`. I want to launch a new Neovim window but nothing too heavy as something built with Qt framework.

Comment: It sounds like you don't have the gui version of neovim and you are trying to open the terminal version as if it was a gui version with its own window.  Try wrapping it in a terminal instead.

Comment: The difference is clear: neovim runs in the terminal, geany doesn't. To follow up on user10489's suggestion: what terminal emulator are you using? You can probably just do something like `nohup gnome-terminal -- nvim &` (or `xfce4-terminal -e` or `konsole -e` or `kitty -e` or whatever in place of `gnome-terminal --`).

Comment: @frabjous Thanks. I use `gnome-terminal`. With `gnome-terminal -- nvim test.txt` I accomplish what I wanted. `gnome-terminal` suggested not using deprecated `-e`: `Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.`